# Post data object using Ajax Web Api

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

I've tried so many samples and couldn't fix the problem.
The current code is successfully posted 1st row.
How to post each row in db using ajax web api?

// post marks students

```
     $('#btnMark').click(function () {
            var date = new Date();
            var obj = {
                "StdntId": $('#studentid').text(),
                "StdntName": $('#fullName').text(),
                "Course": $('#course').text(),
                "Date": date,
                "Status": $('#statusAtt').val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/Test',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer '
                        + localStorage.getItem("accessToken")
                }, 
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#successModal').modal('show');
                },
                error: function (jqXHR) {
                    $('#divErrorText').text(jqXHR.responseText);
                    $('#divError').show('fade');
                }
            });
        });
```

[post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdnf2.jpg)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. without it, we can't say what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: I thought i posted the screenshot my bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to post each row of the table then you have to iterate each row and post the data to server. The drawback of this way is you are sending a lot of request to the server. Alternatively you can iterate each row and store it as array and post all at once.